# Update the color of current rectangle in matplot animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I want to animate the Bubble Sort algorithm with `FuncAnimation`from matplotlib. My idea is to generate a random list of integers and initialize a bar chart plot with the values. Then I apply the `update_fig` function with the generator values for my `bubble_sort` function. So far so good, I am able to animate the whole Bubble Sort algorithm and at the end my array with numbers is sorted.

But for better readability I want to change the color of the current rectangle. For example: All rects should be blue, the current one should be red.

Here is my code:

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def update_fig(a, rects, iteration):
    """
    Function to update the plot
    :param a: the array with numbers
    :param rects: barrect for each number in the array
    :param iteration: the current iteration
    :return: None
    """
    for rect, val in zip(rects, a):
        rect.set_height(val)
        rect.set_color('grey')
    iteration[0] += 1
    text.set_text(f'# of operations {iteration[0]}')


def bubble_sort(a):
    """
    In-place Bubble Sort
    :param a: shuffled array
    :return: rearranged array
    """
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(0, len(a) - i - 1):
            if a[j] > a[j + 1]:
                tmp = a[j]
                a[j] = a[j + 1]
                a[j + 1] = tmp
            yield a

a = list(range(0,100))
random.shuffle(a)
generator = bubble_sort(a)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Bubble Sort')
bar_rects = ax.bar(range(len(a)), a, align='edge')
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, int(1.07 * 100))

text = ax.text(0.02, 0.95, "", transform=ax.transAxes)
iteration = [0]
animate = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                  func=update_fig,
                                  fargs=(bar_rects, iteration),
                                  frames=generator,
                                  interval=1,
                                  repeat=False,
                                  save_count=1500
                                  )
plt.show()
```

The result should be something like [this](https://github.com/lucs123/sorting-visualizer-matplotlib/blob/master/gifs/bubblesort_bar2.gif).

I already tried to set `rect.set_color('orange')` in my update_fig function but this changes the color of all rectangles within the plot at the beginning.

Any ideas how to to this?

Comment: the code is not working. No import and insufficient bracket here `a = list(range(0,100)`

Comment: @aestet sorry I copy&paste only the neccessary parts of my script. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach could be to store the current value into a global variable, which can be checked during coloring. And, while we're at it, also make iteration a global variable.

```py
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

iteration = 0
current_val = None

def update_fig(a, rects):
     """
     Function to update the plot
     :param a: the array with numbers
     :param rects: barrect for each number in the array
     :param iteration: the current iteration
     :return: None
     """
     global iteration, current_val
     for rect, val in zip(rects, a):
          rect.set_height(val)
          rect.set_color('tomato' if val == current_val else 'grey')
     iteration += 1
     text.set_text(f'# of operations {iteration}')

def bubble_sort(a):
     """
     In-place Bubble Sort
     :param a: shuffled array
     :return: rearranged array
     """
     global current_val
     for i in range(len(a)):
          for j in range(0, len(a) - i - 1):
               if a[j] > a[j + 1]:
                    tmp = a[j]
                    a[j] = a[j + 1]
                    a[j + 1] = tmp
               current_val = a[j + 1]
               yield a

a = list(range(0, 100))
random.shuffle(a)
generator = bubble_sort(a)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Bubble Sort')
bar_rects = ax.bar(range(len(a)), a, align='edge')
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, int(1.07 * 100))

text = ax.text(0.02, 0.95, "", transform=ax.transAxes)
animate = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                  func=update_fig,
                                  fargs=(bar_rects,),
                                  frames=generator,
                                  interval=1,
                                  repeat=False,
                                  save_count=1500
                                  )
plt.show()
```